# django: conf.settings missing variables

Tags: python, django

It's recommended to import the settings module as such:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

My `settings` module structure is:

```
├── settings
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── dev.py
│   └── prod.py
```

I have a variable, `amb`, defined in `base.py`, which both `dev.py` and `prod.py` import from:

```
 from .base import *
```

So how come when I do this in a test file:

```
import django

sys.path.append("/path/to/project/")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "root_folder.settings.dev")
# even when the above line is omitted
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.amb) # or settings.AMB
```

I get this error?

> AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'amb'

Same goes if I try `settings.base.amb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.conf.settings` will only return UPPERCASE variables from your settings module. It’s not that lowercase variables are imported as UPPERCASE, they aren’t imported at all.

You can try renaming it to `AMB`.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean it will only return variables that are uppercase, not that it will uppercase values in the file? I think that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `settings.base.amb`

Comment: that returns: "AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'base'"

Comment: Try adding an __init__.py?

Comment: No. @Ian's answer is the correct one. The variable itself should be uppercase, not only my reference to it.